# counting elements after binning data by perl

Tags: perl

I need to count how many different objects I have comparing two files taking into account a particular data binning. The first is a three column file (here `test_counter.txt`) in which are reported ID pairs (the IDs are separated by `|`) and each ID pair has a value associated with. In another file (`list.pl`) I have a simple list of IDs written as `$id{"ID1"} = 1;`. 
So, what do I need is to count the different IDs that I have in the `test_counter.txt` file in each bin (the intervals must be equal to 0.1) and without repetitions (means that if an ID is present twice in the bin I want to count it only once).
The three column file (`test_counter.txt`) looks like this:

```
d|a -0.1412
a|a -0.1526
d|a 0.12
c|b 0.16596
b|a 0.221
c|a 0.21123
d|b 0.388
c|b 0.35
b|d 0.412
d|a 0.5236
d|c 0.565
b|a 0.6174
a|c 0.65
c|d 0.678
```

The `list.pl` file is like this one:

```
$id{"a"} = 1;
$id{"b"} = 1;
$id{"c"} = 1;
$id{"d"} = 1;
```

My desired output is something like this:

```
-0.9 
-0.8 
-0.7 
-0.6 
-0.5 
-0.4 
-0.3 
-0.2 
-0.1 2
0 
0.1 4
0.2 3
0.3 3
0.4 2
0.5 3
0.6 4
0.7 
0.8 
0.9
```

And my code is:

```
    require("id_pf.pl");
    $file = "test_counter.txt";
    open(HAN, "< $file") ||  die "not opening $file";
        @row = <HAN>;
    close(HAN);
    for($i=0;$i<=$#row;$i++) {
        chomp($row[$i]);
        ($ppi,$val) = split(/ /,$row[$i]);
        ($p1,$p2) = split(/\|/,$ppi);
        if ($val <-0.9) {
            $bin= 1;        
        } elsif ($val <-0.8) {
            $bin = 2;
        } elsif ($val <-0.7) {
                $bin = 3;
        } elsif ($val <-0.6) {
                $bin = 4;
        } elsif ($val <-0.5) {
                $bin = 5;
        } elsif ($val <-0.4) {
                $bin = 6;
        } elsif ($val <-0.3) {
                $bin = 7;
        } elsif ($val <-0.2) {
                $bin = 8;
        } elsif ($val <-0.1) {
                $bin = 9;
    } elsif ($val <-0.0) {
                $bin = 10;
        } elsif ($val <0.1) {
                $bin = 11;
        } elsif ($val <0.2) {
                $bin = 12;
        } elsif ($val <0.3) {
                $bin = 13;
        } elsif ($val <0.4) {
                $bin = 14;
        } elsif ($val <0.5) {
                $bin = 15;
        } elsif ($val <0.6) {
                $bin = 16;
        } elsif ($val <0.7) {
                $bin = 17;
        } elsif ($val <0.8) {
                $bin = 18;
        } elsif ($val <0.9) {
                $bin = 19;
    } else {
        $bin = 20;
    }
    if (($id{$p1}) || ($id{$p2})){
    $pos[$bin]++;   
} else {
        }
    }
    for ($k=1;$k<=20;$k++) {
        $bin = ($k/10)-1.05;
        print "$bin\t$pos[$k]\n";
    }
```

Through this code I get this (wrong) result:

```
-0.9 
-0.8 
-0.7 
-0.6 
-0.5 
-0.4 
-0.3 
-0.2 
-0.1 2
0 
0.1 2
0.2 2
0.3 2
0.4 1
0.5 2
0.6 3
0.7 
0.8 
0.9
```

So, pratically my code works only reading the first ID, but not considering the second. And the other mistake is that it counts an ID as many times as it appears in the bin.
Any help is very welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited as per comment. Should work now.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.14.0;

my %hash;
while(<DATA>){
    next if /^\s*$/m; # In case if you have empty lines.
    my ($key1,$key2,$val) = /^(\w)\|(\w) ([0-9.-]+)/;
    $val = int($val*10)/10; 
    $hash{$val}{$key1}++;
    $hash{$val}{$key2}++;
}
for (-9..9){
    $_ = $_/10;
    say "$_\t",ref $hash{$_} ? scalar keys $hash{$_} : '';
}

__DATA__
d|a -0.1412
a|a -0.1526
d|a 0.12
c|b 0.16596
b|a 0.221
c|a 0.21123
d|b 0.388
c|b 0.35
b|d 0.412
d|a 0.5236
d|c 0.565
b|a 0.6174
a|c 0.65
c|d 0.678
```

Output:

```
-0.9    
-0.8    
-0.7    
-0.6    
-0.5    
-0.4    
-0.3    
-0.2    
-0.1    2
0   
0.1 4
0.2 3
0.3 3
0.4 2
0.5 3
0.6 4
0.7 
0.8 
0.9
```

Comment: your code works fine for the example that I wrote here, but it doesn't print properly if the values in the data have two or more decimal numbers...may you suggest something?

Comment: Then you have to change the `for` loop entirely. I guess the best thing is to loop the hash key:`for my $key (sort keys %hash){...}`

Comment: I'm trying something like you suggested, the only problem I cannot bin the data. If I modify my input file, may you help me?

Comment: Sorry that I misunderstood your question. I've modified my answer to solve the problem.

Comment: ..one more question (sorry if I annoy you!): is there a way to print the `keys` and not the `scalar keys` separated by a space or tab? (pratically I don't know where do I have to add this in the `say` command) thank you for patience anyway!